# I want to set image into UIScrollView, but there is a problem. Image is outside of UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I want to set image into UIScrollView, but there is a problem. Image is outside of UIScrollView.
I use [self.scrollView addSubview:view];

[image]

```
enter code here
```

scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollViewRect];

```
 -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sv
 {
    int page = [self currentPage];
    // Load the visible and neighbouring pages 
    [self loadPage:page-1];
    [self loadPage:page];
    [self loadPage:page+1];
}


 -(void)loadPage:(int)page
 {
// Sanity checks
if (page < 0) return;
if (page >= [scrollViewPages count]) return;

// Check if the page is already loaded
UIView *view = [scrollViewPages objectAtIndex:page];

// if the view is null we request the view from our delegate
if ((NSNull *)view == [NSNull null]) 
{
    view = [delegate viewForItemAtIndex:self index:page];
    [scrollViewPages replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:view];
}

// add the controller's view to the scroll view if it's not already added
if (view.superview == nil) 
{
    // Position the view in our scrollview
    CGRect viewFrame = view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.x = viewFrame.size.width * page;
    viewFrame.origin.y = 0;

    view.frame = viewFrame;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:view];
}
```

}

```
enter code here
```

I've attached my project at [my project](https://rapidshare.com/files/3211591559/ScrollView_new.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you assigning desired frame to the view before adding it to the scroll view?

Comment: You can see UIScrollView on my photo. It's behind Balmer's photo and has gray color.

Comment: I downloaded your project. The problem is you have images height as 280 but scroll view height is very less. Please make in the xib, the scroll view height equal to or higher than the highest height of the image and it shall work. If you have any problems, i shall then upload the corrected project. To be more specific, the scroll view height was around 119 and its content size height is 320. Thus, you see the gray area only of the scroll view frame (height 119 px) but it is trying to show image of 280 px in height which is going beyond the gray area.

Comment: I changed scrollView.clipsToBounds from NO to YES. It helped me.